# How to make short lambda of multi join?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 List object (A, B, C) variable. Each of them has its own properties.

I join them to other List D which some of its properties are same with (A, B, C) properties.

This is what I have done. It works for me but I am not satisfied because I have to write some similar lines more than once.

```
IList<A> listA;
IList<B> listB;
IList<C> listC;

...

IList<D> listD = listA
    .Join(listB,
        a=> a.bId, b=> b.Id,
        (a, b) => new
        {
            aId = a.Id,
            aName = a.Name,
            aSample = a.Sample,
            bId = b.Id,
            bName = b.Name,
            bComment = b.Comment,

            cId = b.cId,
        })
    .Join(listC,
        j => j.cId, c => c.Id,
        (j, c) => new List<D>()
        {
            aId = j.aId, // <-- how to not re-write it again
            aName = j.aName, // <--
            aSample = j.aSample, // <--
            bId = j.bId, // <--
            bName = j.bName, // <--
            bComment = j.bComment, // <--

            cId = c.Id,
            cName = c.Name,
            cInterval = c.Interval
        })
    .ToList();
```

What I have to do so I don't need to write: aId, aName, aSample, bId, bName, bComment; in second Join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not like the query syntax (which is preferable here), you can avoid repeating this way:

```
var listD = listA
    .Join(listB,
        a => a.bId, b => b.Id,
        (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .Join(listC,
        ab => ab.b.cId, c => c.Id,
        (ab, c) => new
        {
            aId = ab.a.Id,
            aName = ab.a.Name,
            aSample = ab.a.Sample,
            bId = ab.b.Id,
            bName = ab.b.Name,
            bComment = ab.b.Comment,
            cId = c.Id,
            cName = c.Name,
            cInterval = c.Interval
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple joins more easily using the LINQ expression syntax instead of the LINQ extension methods.  In this case, you would get the same results as the code you posted with this LINQ expression:

```
   var listD =
       from a in listA
       join b in listB on a.bId equals b.Id
       join c in listC on b.cId equals c.Id
       select new {
            aId = a.Id,
            aName = a.Name,
            aSample = a.Sample,
            bId = b.Id, 
            bName = b.Name, 
            bComment = b.Comment, 

            cId = c.Id,
            cName = c.Name,
            cInterval = c.Interval
       };
```